# Not printing http statusCode in react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Its react project and using axios for server communication

I am experimenting server error response (I just put down server for testing)

Problem is I could not track server error status code (I tried to print in console) but I can see status code result in network tab

```
login.js
import { Service } from "./service";

const loginGo = async (e) => {
   let response = await Service(formData);
   console.log(response)
}
```

=====

```
service.js
export const Service = (data) => {
    let response = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.post('/api/auth/login', data, {
        })
            .then(response => {
                resolve(response);
            }, error => {
                reject(error)
            });
    });
    return response;
};
```

I am not sure this is correct way of calling http request, Please correct me if its wrong way

Comment: since `axios.post` already returns a Promise, there is no need to wrap it in a Promise - where is your error handling code in the await? what if the requests rejects? axios will reject if the status code is not between 200 and 299 (unless you change that behaviour, but you don't)

Comment: regarding the Promise constructor anti-pattern I mentioned above, your `service.js` can be just `export const Service = data => axios.post('/api/auth/login', data)`

Comment: @JaromandaX Not luck bro , I can see status code is 504 but , but not printing console.log

Comment: my suggestion for changing service.js has nothing to do with your issue - my FIRST comment mentions error handling .... 504 is NOT between 200 and 299 ... where's your error handling code? (hint: nowhere) ... `async`/`await` is usually paired with `try`/`catch` for error handling

Comment: I expecting all response data should be in //let response = await Service(formData);
   console.log(response) // here , wrong?

Comment: if the status is not between 200 and 299, axios REJECTS - so, no it won't - you'll need a try/catch

Comment: Okay bro , I understand what do you mean

Answer (score -1):

```
axios.get('/user/12345').then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.status);
});
```

Comment: won't do anything on status not between 200 and 299 ....